# uncaughtErrorEvents for loging errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want log client actionscript errors from my aplication. I did reasearch on internet and I found that I should use uncaughtErrorEvents to do this.

I have tryed this.

```
public class Main extends MySprite 
{

    public function Main () 
    {   

        loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, uncaughtErrorHandler);

        var o : Object = null;
        trace(o['something']);              
    }

   private function uncaughtErrorHandler(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
   {
        trace("WHAT");
        if (event.error is Error)
        {
            var error:Error = event.error as Error;
            // do something with the error
            trace(">>>>> ERROR " + error);
        }
        else if (event.error is ErrorEvent)
        {
            var errorEvent:ErrorEvent = event.error as ErrorEvent;
            // do something with the error
            trace(">>>>>> ERROR EVENT " + errorEvent);
        }
        else
        {
            // a non-Error, non-ErrorEvent type was thrown and uncaught
            trace(">>>>>> REALLY NOTHING ");
        }
    }
}
```

Than I simulated error by accessing null object property in code and my game crashed and i did not get any trace msg from uncaughtErrorEvent listener.

Am I using right aproach ? Or should I use different aproach ? What I am doing wrong ?

Also my version of flash is 11.1.

Thank you for any answer

Answer (score 0):

By crash you mean window with stack information about error? Use `preventDefault` method from the Event object, and this window will not show up:

```
private function uncaughtErrorHandler(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void{
     event.preventDefault();
     trace("WHAT");
     // ...
}
```

Comment: When I do this. I dont get any trace msg anyways.

Comment: It works... Check your code. Do you see traces in normal case? Did you add your Main to the display list? Move your testing condition from the constructor to some method